# Generate random numbers from given character set. PHP

Tags: php

How to generate a random from the following list of numbers-

```
a) 1 to 50 (one from the list)
b) 6, 12, 18, 24, 30 (one from the list)
c) 7, 13, 19, 25, 31 (one from the list)
d) 3 to 75 (one from the list)
```

Comment: Okay, that's what you need to do, what are you having issues with? or are you just asking us to program for you?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. you have to show at least the most basic bit of effort at solving your problem

Comment: Here are two functions you could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: Try using `rand(min, max)` for random number from a range & `array_rand(array,number)` for a random item from a predefined set of numbers. Here you go.

Answer (score 1):

Try following that will help you

```
$fixarray1 = array(6, 12, 18, 24, 30);
$fixarray2 = array(7, 13, 19, 25, 31);


$arra1 = rand(1, 50);
$arra2 = array_rand($fixarray1,1);
$arra3 = array_rand($fixarray2,1);
$arra4 = rand(3, 75);

echo $arra1."-".$arra2."-".$arra3."-".$arra4;
```